# How to get the sum of each salary which is order by week?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, lag

I have a table like this

```
Input Table -
          Date          Salary
2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 2321
2020-01-02 00:00:00.000 2414
2020-01-03 00:00:00.000 2323
2020-01-04 00:00:00.000 2324
2020-01-05 00:00:00.000 2325.....so on
```

I have written a query but this query is only giving the sum of previous two weeks for which I have used LAG function

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH,Date) Months,
DATEPART(WEEK,Date) as WeekNo,
SUM(Salary) Salary,
WeekSalary= LAG(SUM(salary)) OVER (PARTITION BY  Datepart(Month,Date) ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH,Date))+SUM(salary)  
FROM SheetTable 
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK,Date),DATENAME(MONTH,Date)
```

Output:

```
Months  Week    Salary  WeekSalary
January    1    9382    NULL
January    2    11681   21063
January    3    55245   66926
January    4    90939   146184
January    5    14091   105030
February    5   2352    NULL
February    6   16492   18844
February    7   16541   33033
February    8   16590   33131
February    9   16639   33229
March      10   16685   NULL
March      11   16730   33415
March      12   16779   33509
March      13   16828   33607
March      14   7227    24055
April      14   9650    NULL
April      15   7248    16898
```

but what if I need a column of total salary till week-
I tried this query

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH,Date) Months,
DATEPART(WEEK,Date) as WeekNo,
SUM(Salary) Salary,
TotalSalary=SUM(salary) OVER (ORDER BY Datepart(week,Date) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM SheetTable 
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK,Date),DATENAME(MONTH,Date)
```

but this getting error:

> Column 'SheetTable.salary' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

**Expected**:

```
Months  Week    Salary   TotalSalary
January    1    9382          9382  --Week(1)
January    2    11681         21063 --week(1+2)
January    3    55245         76308 --week(1+2+3)
January    4    90939         167247--week(1+2+3+4)...so on
```

Comment: Can you set up some test data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ please?

Comment: Sure @Lucero will test their as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you need by using a frame like so:

```
SUM(SUM(salary)) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Comment: You need to window sum the aggregate sum. `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is the shorter version of `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

Comment: @Charlieface Indeed, thank you. I was just trying to get the concept with the frame across since the given example and expectations were not that clear (look at the columns of the `SELECT` and the columns in the "Output :-" example, they don't match at all).

Comment: @Charlieface can you please tell why we have put the sum function again?

Comment: @RishabhKaushik Because the main `GROUP BY` aggregation is already done, and the running total is of the already summed up value `SUM(Salary)`

Comment: Learnt something new today. Very informative thanks for posting. have a good day :)